# Weird comments causing Dream Weaver CC Design View to break

Tags: html, comments, dreamweaver

Here is a picture of the source code for a particular site I have. I've blocked out the actual code.

[image: Source Code]

1. If you'll notice, the comment at the top that says Org Chart is red, but the comment(s) below are both green. Why?
2. Also, while trying to view my code in Dreamweaver CC's Design View, that particular 'Org Chart' comment causes the page to not generate (when I take out that comment, the page loads fine in Design View). Why? Nothing stands out as to why that particular comment is any different.

Note: The comment(s) do not cause any other issues with the page, as far as I can tell. Also, the comments look completely identical in the actual code for the page.

Thanks!

Comment: post your code or a link to the website. I can't tell by just an image.

Comment: @mlegg The site/code is confidential, sorry. It seems the code isn't making a difference, though. It's simply the different types of comments.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it I think I've found the issue.

Comments with 3 or more dashes after/before the opener/closer tags (e.g. '') were red and caused the design view to break. Two dashes makes the comment green and works fine in design view.

This seems to be a bug in Dreamweaver, as it doesn't affect the website at all.